# variable has incomplete type 'void' c++

Tags: c++, computer-science

I came up with a solution for a school assignment however I can't get it to compile. I have five errors and I believe they all stem from me not properly writing my void function. I am still new to coding and I cannot figure this out. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

[image: assignment instructions]

Current Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


void AddList(LinkedList<char>& List, std::string input)
{
    for (int i = input.size()-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        List.add(input[i]);
    } // end for loop
} // end ListTester

bool ifSubString(LinkedList<char>& List, std::string input)
{
    std::string fromTheList = List.toString();
        return (fromTheList.find(subString) != std::string::npos);

}

void AppendList(LinkedList<char>& List, std::string input)
{
    List.clear();
    for (int i = input.size()-1; o >=0; i--)
    {
        List.add(input);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string userString, newstring, substring;
    int choice;
    char charInput;
    LinkedList<char> listik;

    std::cout << "Welcome to the linkedlist program\n" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please Enter the string before we start: ";
    getline(std::cin, userString);
    AddList(listik, userString);
    std::cout << "The string \"" << userString << "\" has been added to the linked list.\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Menu: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Find the length of your input." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. Add a new string to the current string." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3. Find the index of the character." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4. Find matches in the string." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5. Quit and sleep" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::cin.ignore();

    while(choice!=5)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "The List " << listik.toString() << " contains " << listik.getCurrentSize() << " elements." << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "Please type the string you'd like to append to the current list: ";
                getline(std::cin, newstring);
                Appendlist(listik, (userString+newstring));
                std::cout << "The list is \"" << listik.toString() << "\"." << std::endl; //AppendList function contains add method
                std::cout << std::endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Please type the character you'd like to have the index of: ";
                std::cin >> charInput;
                std::cout << "The index of \"" << charInput << "\" is " << listik.getFrequencyOf(charInput) << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "Please type the string you'd like to find in the current list:  ";
                getline(std::cin, subString);
                std::cout << "The string \"" << subString << "\" is";
                if (ifSubString(listik, subString)==false) std::cout << " not";
                std::cout << "found in \"" << listik.toString() << "\"." << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                listik.clear();
                exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `LinkedList`?

Comment: The error happens in any free-function with a `void` return type that has a leftmost parameter with a type that the compiler doesn't recognize. You need to define (or at least declare) the `LinkedList<T>` type.

Comment: What are the compiler errors and the warnings you get? Try configuring your compiler for stricter warnings. Look for project options like `-Wall`. Please quote the messages directly here in full, verbatim and as text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you copied an assignment and introduced a bunch of typos on the way. You need to fill in the blanks in the assignment and implement class template `LinkedList`.

Here is your assignment with your typos removed, you need to implement member functions of `LinkedList`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
struct LinkedList {
    void add(T element);
    std::string toString() const;
    void clear();
    int getCurrentSize() const;
    int getFrequencyOf(T element) const;
};

void AddList(LinkedList<char>& List, std::string input)
{
    for (int i = input.size()-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        List.add(input[i]);
    } // end for loop
} // end ListTester

bool ifSubString(LinkedList<char>& List, std::string input)
{
    std::string fromTheList = List.toString();
    return (fromTheList.find(input) != std::string::npos);

}

void AppendList(LinkedList<char>& List, std::string input)
{
    List.clear();
    for (int i = input.size()-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        List.add(input[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string userString, newstring, subString;
    int choice;
    char charInput;
    LinkedList<char> listik;

    std::cout << "Welcome to the linkedlist program\n" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please Enter the string before we start: ";
    getline(std::cin, userString);
    AddList(listik, userString);
    std::cout << "The string \"" << userString << "\" has been added to the linked list.\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Menu: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Find the length of your input." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. Add a new string to the current string." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3. Find the index of the character." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4. Find matches in the string." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5. Quit and sleep" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::cin.ignore();

    while(choice!=5)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "The List " << listik.toString() << " contains " << listik.getCurrentSize() << " elements." << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "Please type the string you'd like to append to the current list: ";
                getline(std::cin, newstring);
                AppendList(listik, (userString+newstring));
                std::cout << "The list is \"" << listik.toString() << "\"." << std::endl; //AppendList function contains add method
                std::cout << std::endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Please type the character you'd like to have the index of: ";
                std::cin >> charInput;
                std::cout << "The index of \"" << charInput << "\" is " << listik.getFrequencyOf(charInput) << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "Please type the string you'd like to find in the current list:  ";
                getline(std::cin, subString);
                std::cout << "The string \"" << subString << "\" is";
                if (ifSubString(listik, subString)==false) std::cout << " not";
                std::cout << "found in \"" << listik.toString() << "\"." << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                listik.clear();
                exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Read compiler error messages, they tell you what's wrong.